# Box2D debug draw for Android

Tags: java, android, box2d

Is there an implementation of Box2D's DebugDraw for Android? As far as I understand it needs to be written specifically for Android. Other implementations use classes from java.awt, and these won't run on Android's VM.

Comment: Which port of Box2D are you using for Android?

Comment: @XiaoChuanYu I gave up and moved to develop for IOS. Feels so much more native, and when I'm done I'll port to Android. Thanks for answering anyway.